# How can I parse information about certain product from the website (using node.js)?

Tags: node.js, parsing, request, cheerio

I need to parse information from website, for example adidas.com. I'm interested in product  information like this sneakers. How can I get information like cost, image, name and picture of the certain product.

[image: Example of the product]

I tried to use Node.js with modules like cheerio and request but the server had given no info.

```
console.log('In progress!');
const request =  require('request')
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/FY1159?sitePath=us', (error, response, html) => {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    console.log(html);
}
});
```

[image: No information from server]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to perform some web-scraping. Since you're using node,  there's a really popular and extensive module ([Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)) that allows you to scrape data from a web page. You can experiment with it on their playground here: https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

Also, please do keep in mind that there could be legal issues for scraping data from certain pages of a website so I'd recommend looking into that as well. You can view which pages are not allowed/disallowed on the website's `robot.txt` file.

Comment: Okay, I will try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yea no worries! If you've found this answer helpful, I would really appreciate it if you could upvote it or mark it as the approved answer :)